# Magento 1 - how to set a single product for free shipping?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, free-shipping

I want to give the specific product for free shipping and I tried "Attribute" rules and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need use next article [/how-to-set-up-free-shipping-rules-in-magento-2](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-set-up-free-shipping-rules-in-magento-2/)

don't forget about global configuration

Comment: Finally, Resolved!

Answer (score 0):

You can add yes/no variable for free shipping and set yes for Price Rule Conditions then create rules with that attribute. Please check below images.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tadFH.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl2Lc.png
```